# Display div tag corresponding to the string obtained from controller

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have these three div tags in my html.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Success!</strong> Data inserted into OVERRIDE table.
</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Heads up!</strong> Few roles failed. SourceIDs of $uploadResult$ policies mentioned in UI are already present. 
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Snap!</strong> All sourceIDs are already present in OVERRIDE table. 
</div>
```

with a submit button, that calls *submit(parameter)* function in js. That does,

```
$scope.submit = function(employees) {
           $http({
                'url' : '/updateOverride',
                'method' : 'POST',
                'headers': {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                'data' : $scope.employees
            }).success(function(employees){
                $scope.marketForm.texts.push({'text' : employees.text});
                /*$scope.responseMap = employees;*/

               /* document.getElementById('msgTimeout').style.display = "block";
                $( "#msgTimeout" ).load(window.location.href + " #msgTimeout" );*/
            })
        };
```

I now have this controller method that returns either of the 3 strings *SUCCESS*, *WARNING* or *DANGER*.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateOverride", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> addNewElement(@RequestBody String overrideData) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        System.out.println(overrideData);
        DBController dbController = new DBController();
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String insertResult = dbController.mapJSONObject(overrideData);
        System.out.println("\nInsert result:: -> "+insertResult + "\n");
        resultMap.put("updateOverride", insertResult);
        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

I wish to display the corresponding div tag, with respect to the string obtained from controller. (i.e) if *SUCCESS*, first div should be displayed, if *WARNING*, second div should be displayed, and if *DANGER*, the third.

Is there a way this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give id to all three div like

```
<div id="alert_success" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Success!</strong> Data inserted into OVERRIDE table.
</div>
<div id="alert_warning" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Heads up!</strong> Few roles failed. SourceIDs of $uploadResult$ policies mentioned in UI are already present. 
</div>
<div id="alert_danger" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <strong>Snap!</strong> All sourceIDs are already present in OVERRIDE table. 
</div>
```

Then in success callback function

```
success(function(employees){
                $scope.marketForm.texts.push({'text' : employees.text});
                $(".alert").hide();
                var message = employees.text.toLowerCase(); // **assuming SUCCESS**
                $("#alert_"+message).show()


            })
```

Comment: Yes. Good idea. But didnt help Aman ! the div is not getting displayed !

Comment: @Mike  See this https://jsfiddle.net/tLhoj51w/   its working as expected. If its not working for you, then please check the value that you are getting in the message variable. It has to be SUCCESS, WARNING or DANGER in order to work correctly

Comment: oops. yes! That was the issue. Thanks Aman. Good workaround by using the div id in the name of result string. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply build a string that includes the type of div you want to display, use that string as a CSS selector,  and then use your favorite DOM-manipulation mechanism, (jQuery, etc.) to change the `display` attribute from `none` to whatever is appropriate for your page.

```
selector = ".alert.alert-" + type + ".alert-dismissible"
$(selector).Show(...)
```

Comment: My answer is the same idea as what Aman jaura posted;  if I replace Aman's  `$("#alert_"+message).show()`  with  `$('.alert.alert-' + message + '.alert-dismissible').show()`, it operates the same way as Aman's code;  so, same idea, but my answer has a less-complete example;  Aman's answer is the better answer

Comment: Yes. Exactly landru. Even your code worked fine. It was my return type string that was wrong. Accepted Aman's answer purely because it was a little more clear.